# UICollectionview cannot respond to click when it's a subview for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

When i try to add `UICollectionView` to a `UIScrollView` as it's `subview`  strange thing happen : the `UICollectionViewCell` cannot respond to click but long press . It cannot enter `"didSelectedItem"` `delegate` function when i click , but long press can enter .
 How can i fix it ?

Comment: please show your source code

Comment: Why you are add collectionview as subview of scrollview? add some more details. collectionview already provide scrolling and other functionality.

Comment: is that hard to understand?I just alloc a UITableView , then add a UICollectionView to it .All cell in this UICollectionView cannot respond to click (cannot enter "didSelectedItem" function) . Is it some gesture conflict ?